# といった vs といって. What is correct? Why?

Tags: grammar

There is this sentence.

> たたみとかしょうじと（　）日本的なものに興味があります。

From といった and といって, which suits better here? Why?

Along with that can someone please explain what difference is made when といって changes to といった?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Only using 「といっ**た**」 would be correct.  Use 「といっ**て**」 and the sentence will ***not*** make much sense.  It is not even a question of which one is "better".

> 「Enumerated items + といった + Noun」

should be remembered almost as a set phrase meaning:

> "(Noun) such as (enumerated items)"

Thus,

> 「たたみとかしょうじ**といった**日本的{にほんてき}なもの」

means:

> "Japanese things such as tatami and shouji"

「～～といっ**た**」, therefore, is used to introduce actual examples of what one is talking about.

「～～といっ**て**」, however, is very different.  It is used to tell the listener/reader what certain items are called ***and then*** to make an explanatory statement about those items.  I am sure that **you have learned to use the てｰform of a verb as a conjunction**.

For instance, you can say by pointing your finger to the items:

> 「これらは、それぞれ『たたみ』、『しょうじ』といっ**て**、日本で家{いえ}を建{た}てる時{とき}に使{つか}われるものです。」
>
> "These are called 'tatami' and 'shouji', respectively, and they are items used in building houses in Japan."