# What does "...に...といった..." mean here?

Tags: grammar

> 宅配弁当の需要が伸びている。 一般家庭や独り暮し世帯はもちろん、残業で会社に遅くまで残っているサラリーマンに大人気だ。 グルメ時代を反映する高級折り詰め料理やダイエット用の弁当を扱う店も登場。 **いずれの店も笑いが止まらないといった売れ行きである**。

---

> 例えば、本膳料理のメニューには8800 円というおよそ宅配らしからぬ値段の弁当もある。 牛肉のたたき、うなぎのかばやき**に**松茸ご飯**といった**デラックス· メニュー。 こんなのが売れるのかと思ったら、「企業の重役会議や接待に使われている」そうで、なかなかの人気。

---

私はGoogleで「といった」を探しましたが、以下の解釈が出ました。

https://thesaurus.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F
[https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/154790/meaning/m0u/といった/](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/154790/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F/)

以上の解釈は「などの」や「ような」などの意味だと認めています。

なお、Stackexchangeには、「といった」に関する質問がありますが、

[What does といった mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/46680/what-does-%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F-mean)

[Name identification for 安田 味子, and "saying" using という](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/11816/name-identification-for-%E5%AE%89%E7%94%B0-%E5%91%B3%E5%AD%90-and-saying-using-%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%86)

「と言う」に関するので、この質問に満足できませんが、

[といった vs といって. What is correct? Why?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/54793/%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F-vs-%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6-what-is-correct-why)

この質問が「などの」や「ような」に関するので、この質問に満足できるようです。

---

まず、一番目の例では、その例を

> どの店にも、これは笑いが止まらないような売れ行きです

にしてもいいですか。

---

二番目の例では、その例の「に」はどういう意味ですか。

Comment: Related, maybe? : https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/12194/9831

Answer (score 2, accepted):

してもいいですが * 少し意味が変わります。「笑いが止まらないといった売れ行き」は「…止まらない売れ行き」を含みますが、「止まらないような売れ行き」だと必ずしも「止まらない売れ行き」だとは限りません。とても近いだけです。「のような」が比喩なのに対して「といった」は例示です。

次の「に」は、「と」と同じような並列の助詞です。ちがいは、「AとB(と)」が単に両者が同時に存在することを表すのに対して、「AにB」は、まずAがあり、そのうえにBがくっついてくるという感じです。

Edit: * 「どの店**に**も」はよくありません。「どの店も」か「どの店**で**も」になります。場所を表す助詞は「に」ではなく「で」です。「に」が表すのは対象なので、店が笑われていることになってしまいます。

Comment: 後半の説明はその通りで素晴らしいと思います。（+1vote）

Answer (score 1):

「笑いが止まらないといった売れ行き」が「笑いが止まらないような売れ行き」とどのように違うかを比較できるように「ような」を用いて最初の文を言い換えてみますので、違いを感じてください。

「笑いが止まらないと**いった**売れ行き」は「例{たと}えて**言えば**笑いが止まらないような売れ行き」です。
従って、売れ行きの良さを表現するもっと良い方法が見つかったら、例えば「飛ぶ鳥を落とす勢いといった売れ行き」とも言い換えられるかも知れません。
従って「といった」が**例示**であるとするuser4092さんの回答は合っていると思います。